# Non-Continuous UISlider iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uislider

How would I set UISlider so that rather than sliding somewhat continuously, that it only changes to discrete values? I thought of setting the value of the slider at specific intervals but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the return value to an integer?

```
- (IBAction)slider1Changed:(UISlider *)sender {
  NSInteger value = sender.value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method when I need to have step values on sliders.  Change sliderStepValue to whatever you need.

```
-(NSNumber *)updateSliderStepValueWithSlider:(UISlider *)slider {
    NSInteger sliderStepValue = 1.0f;

    float newStep = roundf((slider.value) / sliderStepValue);

    // Convert "steps" back to the context of the sliders values.
    slider.value = newStep * sliderStepValue;;

    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:slider.value];
}

- (IBAction)mySliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSNumber *sliderStepValue = [self updateSliderStepValueWithSlider:sender];  
}
```